# How to get the keyspace name from cassandra session

Tags: database, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

While i am creating the session giving the keyspace_name as input for the API cluster.connect(keyspaceName).Is there anyway/api where i can get the keyspace_name from the session?

Session Creation

```
String cKeyspace="inventory_flip"
Session session = cluster.connect(cKeyspace);
```

How to get keyspace from existing cassandra DB session?

```
session.getXXXXX?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public interface Session extends Closeable {

  /**
   * The keyspace to which this Session is currently logged in, if any.
   *
   * <p>This correspond to the name passed to {@link Cluster#connect(String)}, or to the last
   * keyspace logged into through a "USE" CQL query if one was used.
   *
   * @return the name of the keyspace to which this Session is currently logged in, or {@code null}
   *     if the session is logged to no keyspace.
   */
  String getLoggedKeyspace();
```